Is populating external credentials from VF using connectAPI safe from security review?
I'm packaging the permissions, principals, namedcredentials and externalcredentials with the managed 2gp
However I'm not packaging the external credential principal secret i.e. APIKey for the callout
I'm creating a visualforce page, where user has to populate the APIKey
I'm saving this APIKey inside external credentials, using ConnectAPI and marking the value as encrypted
Is there any part of this flow that would fail security review?
Note: I thought about using Protected Custom Metadata/Setting but they're not useful with NamedCredentials
Or is RemoteSiteSetting with Protected Custom Metadata/Setting is my only option?

Your best bet is to ask the Security Review/Partner Support teams for clarification, but my initial reaction is that this should be acceptable. Named Credentials are purpose-built to keep authentication secrets secure, and the Connect API was purpose-built to give us a way to deal with those secrets securely.

If this approach does get flagged or needs revision, this answer of yours states that OAuth is the preferred approach for external callout authentication.
However I've explored OAuth flows supported by SF and browser flow is the one relevant for me, the limitation with that is SF requires me to implement OIDC auth provider on my web app, is there a workaround where I don't have to become an auth provider?
